# Run a command without output in console

Tags: linux

Sometimes I need to run `dolphin` in console to see the current directory in a GUI (because of some features I've implemented over it).

So I try to do `(dolphin > /dev/null) &` in order not to have many output but I get messages like `QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap` in the console even doing `> /dev/null`

So what's the problem with my command in order not to show output ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to redirect both standard out and standard error to /dev/null.

Try the following.

```
( dolphin > /dev/null 2>&1 )&
```